# How can I record online radio in .NET?

Tags: .net, http, mp3, audio-streaming, shoutcast

I did see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/744619/1796) but not much on .NET...

I want to write .NET code to connect to a web server streaming SHOUTcast (Winamp) audio content (if anyone is interested, the URL is http://live.radiotrinitas.ro:8000/) and record it.

**But I don't know much how to do it**.

*Just open the HTTP connection, and stream it off to a file on the disk?*

There are some headers that appear to be in the content (or so it seems to me) and I don't know what the format is so how to name the extension of the file (MP3?)

---

Update1 :

I did try to connect using HttpWebRequest but it throws up saying ProtocolViolation.
Then I tried connecting using TcpClient and it doesn't send back anything. I guess it awaits some starting command. I don't know this, apparently proprietary (?), protocol...

Comment: The accepted answer (using bass) has a .Net wrapper , did you try it?

Comment: I've downloaded it but I don't get it how it works/what it does. It simply is a thin wrapper around the unamanged (C++) code.

Comment: [You didn't look hard enough](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html#apis):  There is a link to a .Net wrapper API and a link to the documentation.

Comment: I did see the .NET wrapper but the CodeProject solution seemed easier. Although I need to better understand how it works and clean the code..

Comment: Yeah, no need for BASS for this, the SHOUTcast "protocol" is very simple, and the data is just (usually) MP3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems someone over CodeProject posted something useful and working!

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/SHOUTcastRipper.aspx

To run the code snippet you need to set the following configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true"/>
    </settings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```